# Set row format time in agendaWeek view of jquery fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, time-format

How can I change format time in agendaWeek row? Set HH:mm for example.

Answer (score 3):

axisFormat?

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/agenda/axisFormat/

Comment: This does not work:
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            axisFormat: 'h(:mm)tt', ...});

Comment: Worked for me! I think you need version 1.4 for this to work. Thanks!